How to estimate mixture of two normal distributions? With limited data
In finance a mixture of two gaussian models sometimes used. When one normal used to capture the head of the real distribution and another the tail.
$$f(x) = \lambda \cdot \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_1, \sigma_1^2) + (1 - \lambda) \cdot \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_2, \sigma_2^2)
$$
But how to estimate it for specific stock X? There could be not enough data for tail, as by the definition itself tail events are rare.
There are 5 parameters to estimate. Let's try to reduce it and assume that $\lambda=0.5$ and $\mu=\mu_1=\mu_2$ for all stocks (we can validate if our assumption correct by backtesting on lots of various stocks and see how it works).
Now we left with only 3 parameters $\mu,\sigma_1,\sigma_2$. How to estimate it?
For stocks with huge data, that's representative of the real underlying distribution, we can use brute force methods and fit our model.
But, what to do with stocks when there's not enough data, say a) no tail events and we would miss it, or b) the opposite situation - tail event present when there's not much head events, and we may overestimate the tail.
UPDATE: I guess, what I'm asking about, is how to incorporate extra information into the model fitting process. Say we see stock of new tech startup, or new silver mining company, it's been only 3 years on the market, the stock looks nice and smooth. But we have "extra information" - we observed 1000 other stocks, and know that there could be turbulence. So, I guess we need somehow to establish relationship between $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. We can easily estimate $\sigma_1$ (there are enough head events), and then, use it to somehow set lower bound for $\sigma_2 > K\sigma_1$ or something like that.
P.S. Also references to books etc. explaining it in details appreciated.

The EM Algorithm (Expectation Maximization algorithm) is often used for such mixtures. $\mu$ is easy to find (the mean of the empirical distribution). Trial values of $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are assigned and then adjusted iteratively until a good fit to the empirical data is found. It is a ingenious and easy to understand method, well explained in many places.
